# Changed cursor with custom javascript/css but cursor appears about 100px righter and lower than actual pointer

Tags: javascript, css

i'm new at your community (and developing). I have used a code found on internet and changed my cursor into a dot with hover effect. It works great but the only issue that i face is tha cursor does't appear at the right position (i guess about 100px low and right). I would be very glad if you could take a look. I inserted code with WP Coder plugin.

Here is the code i use: https://codepen.io/Maariuss/pen/yWNVOQ
Here is my test page: https://project.rainbowart.gr/cursor-test/

Thanks in advance.

```js
var cursor = {
  delay: 3,
  _x: 0,
  _y: 0,
  endX: window.innerWidth / 2,
  endY: window.innerHeight / 2,
  cursorVisible: true,
  cursorEnlarged: false,
  $dot: document.querySelector(".cursor-dot"),
  $outline: document.querySelector(".cursor-dot-outline"),

  init: function () {
    // Set up element sizes
    this.dotSize = this.$dot.offsetWidth;
    this.outlineSize = this.$outline.offsetWidth;

    this.setupEventListeners();
    this.animateDotOutline();
  },

  setupEventListeners: function () {
    var self = this;

    // Anchor hovering
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function (el) {
      el.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        self.cursorEnlarged = true;
        self.toggleCursorSize();
      });
      el.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        self.cursorEnlarged = false;
        self.toggleCursorSize();
      });
    });

    // Click events
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
      self.cursorEnlarged = true;
      self.toggleCursorSize();
    });
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
      self.cursorEnlarged = false;
      self.toggleCursorSize();
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
      // Show the cursor
      self.cursorVisible = true;
      self.toggleCursorVisibility();

      // Position the dot
      self.endX = e.pageX;
      self.endY = e.pageY;
      self.$dot.style.top = self.endY + "px";
      self.$dot.style.left = self.endX + "px";
    });

    // Hide/show cursor
    document.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
      self.cursorVisible = true;
      self.toggleCursorVisibility();
      self.$dot.style.opacity = 1;
      self.$outline.style.opacity = 1;
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
      self.cursorVisible = true;
      self.toggleCursorVisibility();
      self.$dot.style.opacity = 0;
      self.$outline.style.opacity = 0;
    });
  },

  animateDotOutline: function () {
    var self = this;

    self._x += (self.endX - self._x) / self.delay;
    self._y += (self.endY - self._y) / self.delay;
    self.$outline.style.top = self._y + "px";
    self.$outline.style.left = self._x + "px";

    requestAnimationFrame(this.animateDotOutline.bind(self));
  },

  toggleCursorSize: function () {
    var self = this;

    if (self.cursorEnlarged) {
      self.$dot.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.75)";
      self.$outline.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5)";
    } else {
      self.$dot.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)";
      self.$outline.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)";
    }
  },

  toggleCursorVisibility: function () {
    var self = this;

    if (self.cursorVisible) {
      self.$dot.style.opacity = 1;
      self.$outline.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      self.$dot.style.opacity = 0;
      self.$outline.style.opacity = 0;
    }
  }
};

cursor.init();
```

```css
html,
html *,
body,
body * {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor-dot,
.cursor-dot-outline {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cursor-dot {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: #dc5656;
}

.cursor-dot-outline {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(229, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor-dot-outline"></div>
<div class="cursor-dot"></div>
```

Comment: this is not a custom cursor, this is just a moving element with the cursor

Comment: I found the code described as custom cursor. Sorry for bad definition.

Comment: After quite studying i figured out a big part of this. I created js and css files that include the js and css codes. In functions.php i included these files with wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style. After checking in chrome's developer tools-> sources i see the files. So until here it's good. I think my problem is how to add the class 'cursor-dot' in order to make css functional.